# Linked List Infinite Loop

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

Trying to create a program to count the number of comparisons made with `strcmp` while moving the current node to head. Having some problems with the algorithm though .. it "works" sometimes, and at other times gives me an infiniteloop. Tried lldb for hours now, and put printf messages literally every 2 lines of code, but I have no idea how to pinpoint the problem. I presume it's somewhere in the algorithm but I can't see anything wrong with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node2
{
    char* word;
    struct Node2 *next;
} Node2;

Node2* head = NULL;
Node2* now = NULL;
int uniqueWords = 0;
int totalMTFRComparisons = 0;


Node2* iNode(char* word)
{   
    Node2* ptr = malloc(sizeof(Node2));
    Node2* tmp = head;
    Node2* prev = head;

    while (tmp)
    {
        totalMTFRComparisons++;
        printf("Current word: %s", tmp->word);
        if (strcmp(tmp->word, word) == 0)
        {
            prev->next = tmp->next;
            tmp->next = head;
            return tmp;
        }
        prev = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
        printf("tmp incremented.\n");
    }

    ptr->word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    strcpy(ptr->word, word);
    ptr->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = now = ptr;
        return ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->next = head;
        head = ptr;
    }
    return ptr;
}

char* getString()
{
    static char buffer[128];
    while (fgets(buffer, 128, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        iNode(buffer);
    }
    return buffer;
}

int main()
{
    getString();
    printf("Total words: %d, total MTFR comparisons: %d\n", uniqueWords, totalMTFRComparisons);

    Node2* ptr2 = head;
    Node2* tmp2 = head;
    while (ptr2 != NULL)
    {
        tmp2 = ptr2->next;
        free(ptr2->word);
        free(ptr2);
        ptr2 = tmp2;
    }
}
```

My console is just spammed with:
`tmp incremented.`
But this doesn't always happen - it only happens sometimes, so I have no idea what's causing it.

Example input & output: http://pastebin.com/QfuCm7gt

Comment: You're leaking memory if you use the `return tmp;` path in the loop.  Don't allocate the memory until you know you need it.  However, that won't give you an infinite loop.

Comment: Basic diagnostics: you should print out the word that you're searching for as you enter the function.  In the loop, you should print the word you're comparing with.  If you find a match, you should print that fact before doing the return.  If you don't, you should report as much, allocate the memory (see my previous comment), and  report what else is happening.

Comment: Your code has two malloc calls without freeing after use. There is gonna be huge memory leak.

Comment: @Krypton Worry not friend, the memory is freed elsewhere! Thanks though.

Comment: @Sleepless: Elsewhere? As of now, it looks like the address to the memory allocated seems to have a *local* scope, since `ptr` is local..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're allocating too little memory for your strings:

```
ptr->word = malloc(strlen(word));
strcpy(ptr->word, word);
```

You need to allocate `strlen(word) + 1` bytes to allow for the null terminator.

When you write beyond the allocated space, you invoke undefined behaviour.  Unfortunately for you, that can mean it sometimes appears to work OK — it is a valid response to undefined behaviour to seem to work as expected except when it suits the system to change its mind and behave aberrantly.

Consider whether you can use the `strdup()` function.  If not, consider whether you should write and use your own version of it.  Don't forget to check whether the memory allocation was successful.

(Until you fix the undefined behaviour, there's really no point in wondering what else is wrong, if there is anything else that's wrong.)

---

I wrote this code to see if I could simulate your problem.  I can't:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    char *word;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

int totalMTFRComparisons = 0;

Node* head = NULL;
static Node* iNode(char* word)
{   
    Node* ptr = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node* tmp = head;
    Node* prev = head;

    while (tmp)
    {
        totalMTFRComparisons++;
        if (strcmp(tmp->word, word) == 0)
        {
            prev->next = tmp->next;
            tmp->next = head;
            //tmp->next = prev;

/* JL: Still a memory leak here. */
/* Either free(ptr) or don't allocate until after the loop */

            return tmp;
        }
        prev = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
        printf("tmp incremented.\n");
    }
    ptr->word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    strcpy(ptr->word, word);
    ptr->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = ptr;
        return ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->next = head;
        head = ptr;
    }
    return ptr;
}

static void dump_list(Node *node)
{
    while (node != 0)
    {
        printf("Node word: [[%s]]\n", node->word);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

static void free_list(Node *node)
{
    printf("Freeing list\n");
    while (node != 0)
    {
        Node *next = node->next;
        printf("Freeing: [[%s]]\n", node->word);
        free(node->word);
        free(node);
        node = next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char line[4096];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
    {
        printf("Line: [[%s]]\n", line);
        char *ptr = line;
        char *tok;
        while ((tok = strtok(ptr, "\n\t ")) != 0)
        {
            printf("Word: [[%s]]\n", tok);
            iNode(tok);
            ptr = NULL;
        }
        dump_list(head);
    }
    free_list(head);
    return 0;
}
```

That's more or less an MCVE.  The dump and free functions simply allow me to ensure I can see what's in the list and release all the memory.

Apart from fixing the memory overwriting problem, I only provided a definition for the `Node` type, put `static` in front of the function (to avoid one of the compilation warnings I'd otherwise get), and added the two support functions and `main()`; I didn't change your code otherwise.  (Incidentally, the only complaint on the first compilation was about `cur2` which I'd noticed but forgot to delete — that's very good; few programs, even ones that I write, get through quite that cleanly.)

When run, I typed:

```
abc def ghi
mno pqr stuvwxyz humongously-and-tempestuously-but-neither-abstemiously-nor-facetiously-long word!
```

and I got the output:

```
abc def ghi
Line: [[abc def ghi
]]
Word: [[abc]]
Word: [[def]]
tmp incremented.
Word: [[ghi]]
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
Node word: [[ghi]]
Node word: [[def]]
Node word: [[abc]]
mno pqr stuvwxyz humongously-and-tempestuously-but-neither-abstemiously-nor-facetiously-long word!
Line: [[mno pqr stuvwxyz humongously-and-tempestuously-but-neither-abstemiously-nor-facetiously-long word!
]]
Word: [[mno]]
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
Word: [[pqr]]
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
Word: [[stuvwxyz]]
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
Word: [[humongously-and-tempestuously-but-neither-abstemiously-nor-facetiously-long]]
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
Word: [[word!]]
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
tmp incremented.
Node word: [[word!]]
Node word: [[humongously-and-tempestuously-but-neither-abstemiously-nor-facetiously-long]]
Node word: [[stuvwxyz]]
Node word: [[pqr]]
Node word: [[mno]]
Node word: [[ghi]]
Node word: [[def]]
Node word: [[abc]]
Freeing list
Freeing: [[word!]]
Freeing: [[humongously-and-tempestuously-but-neither-abstemiously-nor-facetiously-long]]
Freeing: [[stuvwxyz]]
Freeing: [[pqr]]
Freeing: [[mno]]
Freeing: [[ghi]]
Freeing: [[def]]
Freeing: [[abc]]
```

When run under Valgrind, I got some curious outputs, but that's because I've upgraded the o/s (Mac OS X Yosemite to El Capitan) without updating the suppressions.  The leaks were all in the system code, not in this code, AFAICT.

---

#### Post-Chat

One of the features of the code is that if the word is entered twice, the word should be moved to the front of the list.  My testing was on unique sets of words.  The problem was in the handling of the duplicate of the first word.  A fix that seems to be robust is in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct Node2
{
    char* word;
    struct Node2 *next;
} Node2;

Node2* head = NULL;
Node2* now = NULL;
int uniqueWords = 0;
int totalMTFRComparisons = 0;

bool DEBUG = true;

static
Node2* iNode(char* word)
{   
    if (DEBUG)
        printf("addNode2 called [[%s]].\n", word);
    Node2* tmp = head;
    Node2* prev = 0;

    while (tmp)
    {
        totalMTFRComparisons++;
        printf("Current word: %s\n", tmp->word);
        if (strcmp(tmp->word, word) == 0)
        {
            printf("Already entered: [[%s]]\n", tmp->word);
            if (prev != 0)
            {
                prev->next = tmp->next;
                tmp->next = head;
                head = tmp;
            }
            //tmp->next = prev;
            return tmp;
        }
        prev = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
        printf("tmp incremented.\n");
    }

    Node2* ptr = malloc(sizeof(Node2));
    printf("New word: [[%s]]\n", word);
    uniqueWords++;
    ptr->word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    strcpy(ptr->word, word);
    ptr->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = now = ptr;
        return ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->next = head;
        head = ptr;
    }
    return ptr;
}

static
char* getString(void)
{
    static char buffer[128];
    while (fgets(buffer, 128, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        char *nl = strchr(buffer, '\n');
        if (nl != 0)
            *nl = '\0';
        printf("Line: [[%s]]\n", buffer);
        iNode(buffer);
    }
    return buffer;
}

int main(void)
{
    getString();
    printf("Total words: %d, total MTFR comparisons: %d\n", uniqueWords, totalMTFRComparisons);

    Node2* ptr2 = head;
    Node2* tmp2 = head;
    while (ptr2 != NULL)
    {
        printf("Freeing: [[%s]]\n", ptr2->word);
        tmp2 = ptr2->next;
        free(ptr2->word);
        free(ptr2);
        ptr2 = tmp2;
    }
}
```

It has some diagnostic printing.  The newline stripping means the diagnostic output is shorter than you'll see in the chat, if you bother to look at the chat (where the strings had a newline at the end — lines were being treated as words, including the newline).

Comment: Tried mallocing `strlen(word) + 1' but the strange loop behavior persists. Will try your other basic diagnostics and comment back momentarily.

Comment: Please also read up on how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
What we've got is not currently an MCVE; we don't have the structure definition (not hard to guess, but we shouldn't have to guess), and we don't have the code that is driving it.  That shouldn't be very hard or big either.  It doesn't need to be your complete program — in fact, it probably shouldn't be.  But it does need to be compilable and complete enough.

Comment: Here is some example input & output: http://pastebin.com/QfuCm7gt

Current word shows what `tmp->word` is per loop revolution

Comment: Updated full code snippet in OP to match MCVE definition.

Comment: @Sleepless: Interesting.  Your definition of word matches my definition of line, but that's tolerable.  It simplifies the MCVE a little.  Taking a look at it more closely.

Comment: I'm getting odd results - though not yet a loop.  Still investigating.  Are you entering the same word twice at all?  I'm not sure what's going on in the code that responds to a duplicate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92920/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-sleepless).

Answer (score 0):

```
ptr->word = malloc(strlen(word));
```

Above Line : incorrect , little memory Ex : strlen("hello") = 5 while sizeof("hello") will give you 6

Changed the line to

```
ptr->word = malloc(sizeof(word));
```

Then after strcpy will work correctly

Comment: That will give size of `char *` . Won't work for every case basically .